# Horizontal ScrollView in collectionView loose functionality

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, collectionview

I have a collection View with different cells. One cell is a horizontal `scrollView` with elements. The `scrollview` is quite similar to the functionality in the "App Store"-App or others.

In the first init it works like expected but when I scroll down in my `collectionView` to the end and then scroll back to my horizontal `scrollView` the contentSize seems to be wrong. So when the `scrollView` cell is reinit the scrollView is like disabled.

The strange thing is when I set a fixed `contentSize` width it works like expected all the time.

```
//calucalte width
var scrollViewWidth:CGFloat = 0
scrollViewWidth = CGFloat(allSkills.count)*scrollViewHeight

cell.skillsScrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
cell.skillsScrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
cell.skillsScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollViewWidth, height: scrollViewHeight)

for (i,imagelink) in imagelinks.enumerated() {
let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollViewHeight, height: scrollViewHeight)) //image is square height and width of scrollView

//set images in 
if i == 0 {
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollViewHeight, height: scrollViewHeight)
} else {
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i)*scrollViewHeight, y: 0, width: scrollViewHeight, height: scrollViewHeight)
}

//set image in ImageValue
//[...]

cell.skillsScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
}

cell.skillsScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewWidth, height: scrollViewHeight) // fixed width = 1000  works like expected but it's too width
return cell
```

My cell is really unexciting.

```
class MySkills: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var contentSkillsUIView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var skillsScrollView: UIScrollView!
}
```

So Im really confused about that behavior. I tried to set the width in `awakeFromNib`. I set the width outside the cell. I init my collectionView in `viewWillAppear` and set my width in `viewDidLoad`. In `prepareForReuse` I set the `contentSize` to 0 too. Everything without changes.

When I print the `scrollViewWidth` it has always the expected value.

So I'm thankful for ideas.

Comment: Can you share demo project?

Comment: have you set up this collectionView in storyBoard? if you have then i can help you otherwise i dont really know how to do stuff programmatically **Suggestion** try adding an NSConstraint (You'll have to do more research about that elsewhere) for the width programmatically

Answer (score 0):

to make a collection view properly there are a long list of steps needed

i will try to make this as clear as possible so bear with me on it

**-GUIDE-**

so assuming you are wanting to have all the cells different based on some variables and some stored data in an array lets get to work cause we have quite a bit of it

step 1.

open up your storyboard and in the ViewController you are wanting to add this collectionView create a new *.swift file* and add these things to it

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class YourViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource { 

}
```

(assuming you are familiar with creating classes and and tying those classes to ViewControllers)

step 2.

in storyboard navigate over to the *identity inspection* tab on the right-hand attributes inspector tab and set your viewController to the class we just created

step 3.

now down at the bottom you want to find and drag a collectionView onto your chosen viewController (**MAKE SURE ITS A COLLECTION VIEW AND NOT A COLLECTION VIEW CONTROLLER**)

step 4.

here is where you can set the size of your cells and the spacing in between each cell etc. (over in the attributes inspector)

step 5.

once you have everything you want you want to add some constraints to this newly created collectionView

-add a *center horizontally in container*

-add a *trailing/leading constraints* to the edges of the viewController

-add a *center vertically in container*

step 6.

now that the collectionView is setup you need to do some coding stuff

hold control and drag from the collectionView (not the collectionViewCell) 
to the viewController (either on the left-hand side or to the top of the viewController where the three symbols are) add the **delegate and datasource** options that pop up (**THESE ARE IMPORTANT IF YOU DONT DO THIS IT WONT WORK**)

step 7.

open up assistant editor and hold control and click and drag from the collectionView to your viewController class file make it an @IBOutlet and name it whatever you want you should have something like this

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource { 

    @IBOutlet weak var YourCollectionView: UICollectionView!


}
```

step 8.

now its time for the really tricky stuff you want to create a new file and choose *cocoa touch class* [image: image 1]

make sure you have it as a subclass of type UICollectionViewCell and click in the *Also create XIB file* check-box you can name this whatever you want [image: image 2]

step 9.

now thats outta the way time for some of the other things required for setup head over to yourViewController class file and add this bit to it

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //or whatever you named the @IBOutlet earlier
    YourCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

now if you build and run now the app will crash thats because the CollectionViewCell we created earlier has not been given a reuse identifier

to fix this head over to the CollectionViewCell XIB you just created and over on the right-hand side (make sure you select the CollectionViewCell before you do this or you wont see anything) [image: image 3]

at the top add a reuse identifier name it whatever you want but make sure its relevant head back to the didmove(toview: _) method in your viewController file at this line here

```
YourCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
```

make sure the *forCellWithReuseIdentifier* string is the same as your reuse identifier you just entered into your XIB cell

step 10.

now you can customize your cell in the XIB file (you can change the size and everything add images and labels etc.) after that open up the assistant editor for the CollectionViewCell XIB and @IBOutlet every label/image you added to the cell give them relevant names that you can easily reference later

step 11.

head back over to your viewController file and create a struct at the top like this

```
struct cellData {
    //here you need to create a *let instance* for every image/label you have in your CollectionViewCell XIB 

    //this is neccesary for determining how to seperate the cells
    let cell : Int!
    //labels will not be declared as a UILabel but as a String like this
    let label : String!
    //images will be declared like this
    let Image : UIImage!

}

class YourViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
```

step 12.

now we are finished with the setup we now have to move on to the customization part of the code

create an empty array inside your class

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource { 


    @IBOutlet weak var YourCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    /* array here */
    var array = [] 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    YourCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

fill the array with the data in your struct like this

```
var array = [cellData(cell : 1,label : "",image : UIImage(named: ""))]
```

ok so lets take a look at this here, we are declaring all the different labels and images in the struct (there should be a label or an image for each label or image you placed in your CollectionViewCell XIB)

now its time for the functionality of the collectionView

step 13.

this whole time you may have been getting an error but we are about to fix it

add these 3 functions to your viewController function

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

}
```

-numberOfSections means how many different sections of cells do you want

-numberOfItemsInSection means how many cells do you want in your sections

step 14.

collectionView is the funtion that determines what is being displayed in each cell you want to add this code inside of it

```
 if array[indexPath.row].cell == 1 {
        //make sure this is the reuse identifier that you have set in your CollectionViewCell XIB
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.image.image = array[indexPath.row].image
        cell.label.text = array[indexPath.row].label

        return cell
    } else {
         let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }
```

step 15.

and thats that if you want to add more cells with different data just put more into your array

```
var array = [cellData(cell : 1,label : "",image : UIImage(named: "")),
             cellData(cell : 2,label : "",image : UIImage(named: "")),
             cellData(cell : 3,label : "",image : UIImage(named: ""))]
```

and then make sure it is being loaded in with your collectionView function

```
if array[indexPath.row].cell == 1 {
        //make sure this is the reuse identifier that you have set in your CollectionViewCell XIB
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.image.image = array[indexPath.row].image
        cell.label.text = array[indexPath.row].label

        return cell
    } 
    if array[indexPath.row].cell == 2 {
        //make sure this is the reuse identifier that you have set in your CollectionViewCell XIB
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.image.image = array[indexPath.row].image
        cell.label.text = array[indexPath.row].label

        return cell
    }
    if array[indexPath.row].cell == 3 {
        //make sure this is the reuse identifier that you have set in your CollectionViewCell XIB
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.image.image = array[indexPath.row].image
        cell.label.text = array[indexPath.row].label

        return cell
    } else {
         let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }
```

make sure in your array you set the *cell* Int to increasing Integer values or the cells wont load also to customize the data in each cell just fill in the blanks in your array

```
var array = [cellData(cell : 1,label : "Blank here",image : UIImage(named: "Blank here"))]
```

if you have any questions comment them